# Mongoose - How get the element removed from $pull

Tags: mongoose

I have schema mongoose

```
var postSchema = new Schema({
    comments: [{
        nickName: {type: String, required: true}, 
        comment: {type: String, required: true}
    }]
});
```

And then I want to pull one comment of comments

```
Post.findOneAndUpdate({'_id': req.body._id}, {$pull: {'comments': {'_id': req.body._idComment} }},
  function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        res.send({status:400});
    } else {
        // how get $pull object if I don't know index of element of array
        // data returns all objects
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this. But there are few workarounds for it. 
Update the data ( i mean remove it ) and if it is successful then you know that your input to remove the element is your answer.

```
Post.update({'_id': req.body._id}, 
   {$pull: {'comments': {'_id': req.body._idComment} }},function(err, data) {
      ....
      ....
});
```

You can also run a `find` query to check if your data is removed which will also confirm your removed data.

Otherwise `findOneAndUpdate` return the updated doc using `{new:True}` option and you can compare your input with returned doc to get the removed data.